# Removing Unnecessary Vertices on Mesh Like Terrain

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, vertices

Actually the tittle not correct at all but I can't find any words to describe my problem. I'm using blender and ripper for reach to my favorite game's map.

I don't have any problem importing etc. This my imported model;
[image]

As you see, there is too much grass, rocks and trees on the terrain of mesh. This is my problem. Is there any way to remove other-terrain objects in blender (or any other modelling software)? The terrain is continious but other objects start vertices have an angle bigger than normal angle which used by terrain continue vertice. Look that image:

[image]

Otherwise, if you see the second image, the terrain have tilled (e.g. 2x2, 4x4 I don't know the magnitude) squares basically. Maybe this can give a way for solve my problem. Is there any way?

Thank You..

Comment: Just for clarification, all geometry is in a single object and you want extract the terrain mesh (or remove objects that are not terrain)?

Comment: Yes, we can say that :D

Comment: But I can't select every part, because too much vertices there. Is it automated system? I can't understand.

Comment: You can select a single vertex of the terrain and then use *Select Linked* (Ctrl + L). Once the terrain is selected press P to separate the selection into a separate object.

Comment: Hello again, I tried your way but it not selected every terrain, only selected one square of terrain like this; https://imgur.com/a/SzULKas

Comment: Your terrain mesh isn't connected then.  Perhaps selecting by material is quicker, if you have a smaller number of materials for the terrain and they aren't shared with non terrain objects.

Comment: Hmm, then there is no way other?